# HTML (PHP) linking CSS files

Tags: php, html, css

I have maybe ten .php files that make up the main pages of my website and 20 .css files all in all. I noticed that when I made a submit button in one file, it adopted the attributes of a .css file that I had not linked through the normal html way.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

However, I have referenced other .php files like this:

```
include('config.php');
```

And then in config I referenced many other files in some kind of tangled web.

Does that mean that css is passed on through the PHP include method - and that in multiple layers? e.g. if I referenced a file in config.php that didn't directly reference a css file, but instead another php file which maybe DID directly reference css.

I have to apologize if this is a slightly confused question, it's just my mind cannot comprehend this... CSSCeption...

Comment: include is much the same as pasting the code directly, so yes, if you include a php file with any css linked, it will be linked on that page

Comment: you need to restructure the whole thing by the sounds of it

Comment: Say what: 20 .css files?

Comment: css files are being called AFTER the html page is generated. Just check your page source code and search all .css files you request

Comment: unless you desire to become a developer (not recommended), how about using a pre-existing CMS.

Comment: @Dagon is that a Control Management System? And why is becoming a developer not recommended?

Comment: content management system. and because i am, and hate my job ;)

Comment: @Dagon, thanks for the advice on cms. I was kind of aspiring to become a developer :), why is your job so bad?

Comment: @Dagon  Developer here, love my job.  Find a better place to work ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this...  If you go to your site and right click the page and click view source.  You will see your entire document, including any items that might be included.

Think of it in this way.  An include, is a sort of way of saying, at this position in the document, there should be other things.  It looks for the file you include and takes it's contents, whatever that is, and sticks those contents where the include is, it will do this with every include until it finally reaches the end of the document.

In this way, it brings in HTML that has your CSS files linked, and then it reads the HTML that it just brought in, and it applies those CSS files styles to the entirety of the document after all of the HTML has been loaded.

Comment: Ah, so using the link tags in html is also copy/paste or something of the sorts?

Comment: The <link> tag is very much like a php include, or you could say a php include is very like a <link> tag.  You could also say <img> tags are similar to those as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must know that `CSS` doesn't "know" what `php` means, **`CSS` defines HOW HTML elements are to be displayed**. So it will take place after the `web server` converts all your `php` code into `html`.